# Delays in application after system startup

Tags: c++, logging, delay, system-calls

I have application (single-threaded) which is triggered by Windows event every time OS booted successfully.

Once for a dozen or so launches I'm observing crash of my application which was not able to send data to service on time. After investigation I found code sector which is causing problem (taking too much time).

I could not reproduce this manually so I've placed some brutal logging to my code in smelly lines.

I found that delay between lines 58 and 59 is close to 1.5 sec!

```
...
LIF_DBG << "LINE 58";
Buffer request(static_cast<uint32_t>(cmdSize)); // around 50-100 bytes
LIF_DBG << "LINE 59";
...
```

Buffer constructor:

```
Buffer(uint32_t size_) : buf(nullptr), size(size_)
{
    buf = new uint8_t[size];
    if (buf != NULL && size > 0)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, size);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Delay occurs not only in this line, I observe strange delays on other lines which indirectly call *new*, *malloc()*, *memset()* etc.

I don't understand what can cause this strange behavior, I bet two options:

1. Delay on syscalls
2. Logger sometimes is causing delays (Less likely because originally logging was outside smelly code sector)

What can I do more to find the root cause?

Comment: lots of `malloc` calls can cause memory fragmentation which can take time.

Comment: You could record a trace with [xperf/WP](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/etw-central/) which would tell you what's happening on the system level during the call to malloc/memset.